# how to invoke web url from power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to invoke web url from Power BI using Web data source in Power BI. But I'm unable to achieve.

We have requirement that users can click button on power bi so it should trigger or invoke web url in the backed there is another job or task will trigger when user click on button.

I'm doing invoke web url from powershell using below code, so want to get this to be from power bi.

```
$data =@{
"emailId"= "xxxxxxx"
"emailSubject"= "xxxxx"
"emailBody"= "xxxxx"
}

$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json

$LogicAppsUrl = "https://prod-83.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxx"
$LogicAppInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LogicAppsUrl -Headers @{
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
} -Method Post -Body $json -UseBasicParsing

Write-Host "Trigger Complete"
```

How can we achieve same using Power BI? Is there any option we can do ?

Please suggest any alternative plans to do from power bi.

Thanks,
Brahma

Comment: I suggest you to use Power Automate, it have integration object in Power BI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-automate-visual?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: thank you @Lev Gelman for your response

The idea behind of this is:

We have power BI reports that connect to Azure Analysis service so we do not want to run the azure analysis service 24x7.

Users can verify the azure analysis service status, then if it is in Off state they can resume it and start using the power BI reports.

Users can submit click button on Power BI report to see the status of Azure analysis service and they can start service from power BI itself.

Intension is to keep this feature in Power BI itself instead of other services options like Power Automate.

Comment: I did it in a past. I had 2 power automate flows:

1)Check for Azure Analysis Service state and return it to Power BI
2)Turn the Azure Analysis Services on

Comment: thank you so much @Lev Gelman. It is really help full. Shared article to solve my requirement.

Comment: Hi @Lev Gelman.  I have One question, How to pass custom parameters from Power BI instead default.  Like I'm using automation account passing parameters  1) Subscription ID 2) Resource GroupName 3) Server Name.  Because we have too many Azure analysis services and power BI reports. so can't create too many Power Automation.

Comment: The question is why you need Power BI here. I did it by creating Power Apps, that can manage your Analysis in Azure. Power Apps can run Power Automate with parameters. (you can send parameters and get it back). 
As an idea you go to your Azure subscription and get list of all your Analyses Services instances, return the list to Power Apps and then let the user to choose and manage them.